# What's the difference between can,could and may?

Tags: grammar, american-english

What's the difference between **can**,**could** and **may**?

I'm an English learner,can you help me?

I'm from China,so I can't understand them...

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They all have unique meanings which a dictionary will tell you. However, they can be interchangeable in certain contexts.

"Can" indicates that something is a possibility *eg. "I can go to the shops for you"*

"Could" indicates a possibility that is perhaps dependent on something a condition *eg. "I could go to the shops for you if I can borrow your car"*

"May" can indicate an uncertain possibility *eg "I may go to the shops today, or maybe tomorrow"*

An example where "could" and "may" are interchangeable would be:

> Q. Who is knocking at the door?
>   A. It could be my dad / It may be my dad

Comment: so,can we say"may I borrow your book?" or "could i borrow your book?"or"can i borrow your book?"?

Comment: @YangJingbo You could say any - but the *polite* question is "May I borrow your book" - because it is indicates uncertainty, so is the least presumptuous. (you should have said in your question that you wanted to use these words in a question)

Comment: Thanks! I get it.